# Criação de data base através do StringBuilder

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, stringbuilder

Estou criando meu banco de dados com a classe `sqliteOpenHelper`, passando a criação do DB por `String` através do `StringBuilder`.
O problema, é que só está criando a primeira tabela, e depois não cria a próxima, nesse caso estou criando primeiro a cidade. Se eu invertesse colocando a consumo por primeiro e as outras em sequência, ela criaria a consumo e não criaria a próxima, ou seja ele sempre cria a primeira tabela apenas.

Pensei que poderia ser por motivo de limite de caracteres, então usei o `str.ensureCapacity(10000);` mas sem sucesso.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    str.append("CREATE TABLE cidade (");
    str.append("_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, ");
    str.append("nome VARCHAR(20), ");
    str.append("estado VARCHAR(2), ");
    str.append("vlaguaI DECIMAL, ");
    str.append("vlaguaII DECIMAL, ");
    str.append("vlaguaIII DECIMAL, ");
    str.append("vlinicial_faixa_consumoI INTEGER, ");
    str.append("vlfinal_faixa_consumoI INTEGER, ");
    str.append("vlinicial_faixa_consumoII INTEGER, ");
    str.append("vlfinal_faixa_consumoII INTEGER, ");
    str.append("vlinicial_faixa_consumoIII INTEGER, ");
    str.append("vlfinal_faixa_consumoIII INTEGER, ");
    str.append("vl_esgoto DECIMAL, ");
    str.append("vl_taxa_afastamento DECIMAL); ");

    str.append("CREATE TABLE consumo (");
    str.append("_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, ");
    str.append("dt_leitura DATE), ");
    str.append("registro INTEGER, ");
    str.append("vl_consumo DECIMAL); ");

    str.append("CREATE TABLE configuracao (");
    str.append("_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, ");
    str.append("id_cidade INTEGER NOT NULL, ");
    str.append("hidrometro INTEGER, ");
    str.append("CONSTRAINT fk_configuracao ");
    str.append("FOREIGN KEY(id_cidade) ");
    str.append("REFERENCES cidade(_id)); ");

    str.append("CREATE INDEX configuracao.fk_configuracao_idx ON configuracao(id_cidade); ");

    db.execSQL(str.toString());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, como o Maniero apontou na [resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97500/132), você deixou um abre parênteses a mais aqui:

```
    str.append("CREATE TABLE consumo (");
    str.append("_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, ");
    str.append("dt_leitura DATE), "); // <--- ERRO!!!!
    str.append("registro INTEGER, ");
    str.append("vl_consumo DECIMAL); ");
```

Segundo, como o ramaral apontou na [resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97501/132), o `execSQL()` só executa uma instrução por vez.

Terceiro, não tem sentido usar o `StringBuilder` desse jeito. As `String`s são imutáveis e fixas, então é melhor construí-las antecipadamente ao invés de construí-las todas as vezes que o método for executado. Além disso, o compilador é bem esperto, e ele sabe quando otimizar a concatenação de `String`s fixas com o operador `+` de forma a gerar um *bytecode* aonde a `String` já aparece concatenada. Entretanto, se você faz isso manualmente usando o `StringBuilder`, o compilador não será capaz de fazer esta otimização.

Assim, o seu código fica bem melhor desta forma:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_CIDADE = ""
        + "CREATE TABLE cidade ("
        + "    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
        + "    nome VARCHAR(20),"
        + "    estado VARCHAR(2),"
        + "    vlaguaI DECIMAL,"
        + "    vlaguaII DECIMAL,"
        + "    vlaguaIII DECIMAL,"
        + "    vlinicial_faixa_consumoI INTEGER,"
        + "    vlfinal_faixa_consumoI INTEGER,"
        + "    vlinicial_faixa_consumoII INTEGER,"
        + "    vlfinal_faixa_consumoII INTEGER,"
        + "    vlinicial_faixa_consumoIII INTEGER,"
        + "    vlfinal_faixa_consumoIII INTEGER,"
        + "    vl_esgoto DECIMAL,"
        + "    vl_taxa_afastamento DECIMAL"
        + ");";

private static final String SQL_CREATE_CONSUMO = ""
        + "CREATE TABLE consumo ("
        + "    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
        + "    dt_leitura DATE,"
        + "    registro INTEGER,"
        + "    vl_consumo DECIMAL"
        + ");";

private static final String SQL_CREATE_CONFIGURACAO = ""
        + "CREATE TABLE configuracao ("
        + "    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
        + "    id_cidade INTEGER NOT NULL,"
        + "    hidrometro INTEGER,"
        + "    CONSTRAINT fk_configuracao"
        + "    FOREIGN KEY(id_cidade)"
        + "    REFERENCES cidade(_id)"
        + ");";

private static final String SQL_CREATE_CONFIGURACAO_INDEX =
        "CREATE INDEX configuracao.fk_configuracao_idx ON configuracao(id_cidade);";

private static final String[] SQLS = {SQL_CREATE_CIDADE, SQL_CREATE_CONSUMO, SQL_CREATE_CONFIGURACAO, SQL_CREATE_CONFIGURACAO_INDEX};

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    for (String s : SQLS) {
        db.execSQL(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Amigos, muito obrigado a todos pelas respostas,
realmente no trecho  str.append("dt_leitura DATE), "); estava incorreto, pois eu estava fazendo testes, comentando algumas linhas da tabela pensando que era por excesso de string que não estava criando, mas já havia corrigido e não alterei no post, desculpe.

Referente a resolução do meu problema , optei por utilizar a do Victor Stafusa, que funcionou corretamente.

Muito obrigado a todos.
abraço

Answer (score 3):

O problema está nesta linha:

```
str.append("dt_leitura DATE), ");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/QueryBuilder.cs).

Você fecha o parêntese e depois continua, o que gera um erro de sintaxe.

Answer (score 3):

Na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) poderá verificar que o método `execSQL()` só executa uma instrução SQL de cada vez.

Terá de construir cada um dos "Create Table...", um de cada vez e executá-los à vez.

Answer (score 2):

Conforme dito pelo *ramaral*, a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) do `execSQL()` aponta que o método só executa um SQL por vez.
O que você pode fazer é criar um `StringTokenizer` para dividir as instruções SQL e executá-las uma a uma. Ficaria algo neste sentido:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer( str.toString(), ";", false);

while ( tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() )
{
    db.execSQL(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

Nesse caso, você estaria dividindo o seu `StringBuilder` a cada `;` encontrada. Ou seja, cada SQL será executado separadamente dentro do `while`.

Verifique também este trecho: `str.append("dt_leitura DATE), ");`, onde você fecha o parênteses antes de terminar a instrução SQL.